# Setup Windows Deployment Services when option 66 is already in use

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, deployment, pxe-boot, wds

I am currently trying to setup WDS at my company.

The WDS and DHCP are running on two different servers.

However, our IP telephony system is currently using option 66 (Boot Server Host Name) in order for the phones to boot/direct to the Telephony Server.

We have confirmed that the phones do normal DHCP boots and not PXE boots, so we had the idea of setting up DHCP on the WDS server and a new scope, and then have the Core switch point all PXE requests to the WDS server.

Is something like this possible?

Or could you perhaps recommend an alternative method?

Many thanks!

John

Comment: Are the phones not on a tagged vlan and the workstations on an untagged vlan?  That would facilitate the 2 different scopes on the same DHCP server that exists already.

Answer (score 0):

If the phones aren't performing PXE boot, you should be able to use the vendor class id DHCP option to tell them apart in the DHCP server. PXE requires the vendor class to be "PXEClient".